# Maui application ceased to work on Android

Tags: android, maui

When I run it upon deployment (which completes successfully) application crashes with this message:

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: MauiContext should have been set on parent.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view)
   ...
```

When I try to debug it, this exception is thrown instantly, before the execution reaches my code:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C# 
    ...
```

Have no idea of what to do, please help... I have been developing this application for months, and everything was ok before this day.

PS: target platforms .NET 7.0, Android 13.0 (API 33)

Comment: I have found similar issues : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16919 ,
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18070 take a look there.